# How can I untar a file in an android app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, tar

I have a ".tar" file that my app downloads and I can't figure out how to extract it. I've tried reading it with ZipInputStream, but getNextEntry() returns null even though I can confirm through terminal that the tar file exists. I've been able to untar it manually so I know it's not an issue with the file.

Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try with `GZIPInputStream`? Also, take a look on [JTAR](https://github.com/kamranzafar/jtar)

Comment: GZIPInputStream gave me an IOException... unexpected magic number 6316 or something along those lines. I haven't tried JTAR though, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested above, JTAR ended up working for me:
https://github.com/kamranzafar/jtar